# Use Chrome Driver for Selenium in Centos 7 server *** WebDriverException: Message: chrome not reachable

Tags: python, linux, google-chrome, selenium

I am **scraping** data from a website, I used the selenium to crawl data, data crawling working fine in my local machine with chromedriver, as chrome driver open a chrome windows while **scraping** data, So I deployed my code on Centos7, but I am getting an error while executing my **scraper**

```
      *** WebDriverException: Message: chrome not reachable
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.9.248316,platform=Linux 3.10.0-514.16.1.el7.x86_64 x86_64)
```

I install chrome on Centos I used

```
      from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
      display = Display(visible=0, size=(800, 600))
      display.start()
      self.trivago_scraper(hotel_name, filename)
      display.quit()
```

but it's not working please let me know where I am wrong, and how can I fix this on Centos instance.

Comment: Hi, did you ever figure this out?

Comment: Yes, I was using the wrong bit of chrome driver, that fixed my issue.